Problems with deploying shiny app to shiny.io "unable to satisfy package: xtable (1.8-6)"
I am trying to deploy a shiny app on shiny.io, but for some reason, no matter what I try to deploy, I get this error message:
Waiting for task: 1448925532
  building: Building image: 10931400
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Building package: xtable
## Begin Task Log ##############################################################
## End Task Log ################################################################
Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1448925533 child_task_status=failed: Error building image: Error fetching xtable (1.8-6) source. <CRANPackageSource repo='http://cran.rstudio.org'> unable to satisfy package: xtable (1.8-6)
Execution halted

I am not even sure where to start to fix it! I have tried installing xtable with install.package("xtable"). I am not sure what else to do! I have tried looking in other posts but can't seem to find a solution that makes sense to me.

That should be install.packages("xtable") and not install.package(). Take note of the s.

Thank you for this correction! Still does not fix the problem! Not sure why

Check to make sure that all of the xtable dependencies are available. Additionally, some packages call up there defaults and supporting packages when you call the library. Make sure all of the necessary libraries are called in the initial part of the code. They shouldn't be called in the io, server, or only with the :: (for joining packages and functions).

I looked for dependencies with tools::package_dependencies("xtable", recursive = TRUE). The only packages that came up were stats and utils, which I then put on the top of script. but it is giving me the same error message.

I reposted with the full script above

Found out the error! I was downloading xtable from rforge instead of CRAN and CRAN did not have version 1.8.6
